# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ Setup Issue: "error: ‘TLSv1_method’ is deprecated"

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, iot

I am setting up a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and connecting it to an IoT hub on Azure by following the instructions in the manual below:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/

After attempting to build the updated sample solution in step 1.6, the Raspberry Pi's terminal displays this (as the build fails to complete):

```
    [ 59%] Building C object azure-iot-sdks/c/azure-c-shared-utility/CMakeFiles/aziotsharedutil.dir/src/x509_openssl.c.o
    /home/pi/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/azure-iot-sdks/c/azure-c-shared-utility/src/tlsio_openssl.c: In function ‘create_openssl_instance’:
    /home/pi/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/azure-iot-sdks/c/azure-c-shared-utility/src/tlsio_openssl.c:713:5: error: ‘TLSv1_method’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
    tlsInstance->ssl_context = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_method());
    ^~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ct.h:13:0,
             from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:61,
             from /home/pi/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/azure-iot-sdks/c/azure-c-shared-utility/src/tlsio_openssl.c:9:
    /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1612:1: note: declared here
    DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_method(void)) /* 
    TLSv1.0 */
    ^
    cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
    azure-iot-sdks/c/azure-c-shared-
    utility/CMakeFiles/aziotsharedutil.dir/build.make:950: recipe for target 'azure-iot-sdks/c/azure-c-shared-
    utility/CMakeFiles/aziotsharedutil.dir/src/tlsio_openssl.c.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [azure-iot-sdks/c/azure-c-shared-
    utility/CMakeFiles/aziotsharedutil.dir/src/tlsio_openssl.c.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    [ 60%] Building C object azure-iot-sdks/c/iothub_service_client/CMakeFiles/iothub_service_client.dir/src/iothub_registrymanager.c.o
    [ 61%] Building C object azure-iot-sdks/c/iothub_service_client/CMakeFiles/iothub_service_client.dir/src/iothub_messaging_ll.c.o
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1042: recipe for target 'azure-iot-sdks/c/azure-
    c-shared-utility/CMakeFiles/aziotsharedutil.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [azure-iot-sdks/c/azure-c-shared-
    utility/CMakeFiles/aziotsharedutil.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    [ 62%] Building C object azure-iot-sdks/c/iothub_service_client/CMakeFiles/iothub_service_client.dir/src/iothub_service_client_auth.c.o
    [ 62%] Building C object azure-iot-sdks/c/iothub_service_client/CMakeFiles/iothub_service_client.dir/__/iothub_client/src/iothub_message.c.o
    [ 63%] Linking C static library libiothub_service_client.a
    [ 63%] Built target iothub_service_client
    Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am unable to get past this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there's a cleaner way to work around this but if you remove `-Werror=deprecated-declarations` from the Makefile you should be good.

Comment: Hi Doe, have you tried method @evilSnobu ? Issue solved?